# installing npm package from github fork leads to missing files

Tags: reactjs, npm-install, yarnpkg, react-vis

while I can run `yarn add react-vis` just fine, when I run `yarn add richardlewisjones/react-vis`, I get these errors:

```
error: (client) ./node_modules/react-vis/es/index.js
error: (client) ./node_modules/react-vis/dist/style.css
```

and was wondering how I can resolve these errors.

Comment: remove **package-lock.json** and then run **npm install**

Comment: also check this https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2534